# How do I theme forms elements differently based on location of form

Tags: users

I am using MYTHEME_form_element to customize the markup around individual elements. For example I wrap everything in DIV's except checkboxes and radios.

Now I have added a login toolbar to the website. These input controls should not have DIV's around them. But given the context of the hook I cannot determine which form they are from so i cannot conditionally remove the DIV's around *only* the form elements in the login_block.

Any ideas???

Comment: I added a conditional test for #id and whether edit-name--2 or edit-pass--2 were existant. This worked until I navigate to any other page and my login block is the only form then it's ID becomes 1...ugh

Comment: I think you should be able to get form_id, and use form ID to skip wrapping login form. Try it like [this](http://heididev.com/06/18/2011/how-theme-drupal-form-using-tplphp-file) so you'll get form based wrapping instead of element based.

Comment: Problem is, I have two login forms on a single page...one is always visible (when not logged in) as a toolbar at top of page. When credentials are wrong they get redirected to standard content login form where they are shown errors, etc.

Comment: As a side note...I kinda solved the problem by detecting user_login_block in MYTHEME_form_alter() and added custom variables to the $elements which I can then check inside the HOOK_form_element and render accordingly.

Comment: You can duplicate the form using [`hook_forms()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7) and then theme based on form_id